# The Ingress Controller is not created when running the "minikube addons enable ingress"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I have minikube installed on Windows10, and I'm trying to work with [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/)

I'm doing:

> $ minikube addons enable ingress

```
* After the addon is enabled, please run "minikube tunnel" and your ingress resources would be available at "127.0.0.1"
  - Using image docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1
  - Using image k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.44.0
  - Using image docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1
* Verifying ingress addon...
* The 'ingress' addon is enabled
```

> minikube addons list

```
 minikube addons list
|-----------------------------|----------|--------------|
|         ADDON NAME          | PROFILE  |    STATUS    |
|-----------------------------|----------|--------------|
| ambassador                  | minikube | disabled     |
| auto-pause                  | minikube | disabled     |
| csi-hostpath-driver         | minikube | disabled     |
| dashboard                   | minikube | disabled     |
| default-storageclass        | minikube | enabled ✅   |
| efk                         | minikube | disabled     |
| freshpod                    | minikube | disabled     |
| gcp-auth                    | minikube | disabled     |
| gvisor                      | minikube | disabled     |
| helm-tiller                 | minikube | disabled     |
| ingress                     | minikube | enabled ✅   |
| ingress-dns                 | minikube | disabled     |
| istio                       | minikube | disabled     |
| istio-provisioner           | minikube | disabled     |
| kubevirt                    | minikube | disabled     |
| logviewer                   | minikube | disabled     |
| metallb                     | minikube | disabled     |
| metrics-server              | minikube | disabled     |
| nvidia-driver-installer     | minikube | disabled     |
| nvidia-gpu-device-plugin    | minikube | disabled     |
| olm                         | minikube | disabled     |
| pod-security-policy         | minikube | disabled     |
| registry                    | minikube | disabled     |
| registry-aliases            | minikube | disabled     |
| registry-creds              | minikube | disabled     |
| storage-provisioner         | minikube | enabled ✅   |
| storage-provisioner-gluster | minikube | disabled     |
| volumesnapshots             | minikube | disabled     |
|-----------------------------|----------|--------------|
```

**Note**:
I ran `minikube tunnel` after the addon was enabled

But can't see the nginx controller anywhere:

> $ kubectl get pods -n kube-system

```
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-74ff55c5b-8gkwj            1/1     Running   0          2m35s
etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   0          2m48s
kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   0          2m48s
kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running   0          2m48s
kube-proxy-jq4wm                   1/1     Running   0          2m35s
kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running   0          2m48s
storage-provisioner                1/1     Running   2          2m47s
```

> $ kubectl get pods

```
No resources found in default namespace.
```

Comment: Hello @zbeedatm and welcome to Stack Overflow! Everything you did seems right except one thing. The Ingress Controller will be created in the ingress-nginx namespace. Could you please check there?

Comment: Hello @WytrzymałyWiktor, thanks... yep it's there, I was following this tutorial https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#what-s-next and in step 2 it was mentioned that it should be under kube-system namespace (I guess different versions issue). However after I carried on with further steps it worked for me, so I knew it's there somewhere but couldn't indicate where. Thanks again

Comment: Good to hear that. I'm going to compose an answer in a moment for better visibility.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments the Ingress Controller will be created in the `ingress-nginx` namespace instead of the `kube-system` namespace. Other than that the rest of the tutorial should work as expected.

Comment: However, when I went over the same tutorial with minikube on LINUX machine, the ingress controllers were in the 'kube-system' namespace.

Comment: Thankyou. It's been driving me nuts.